# Why more than one "render" method is allowed in React JS, which the latter overrides the former?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why more than one "render" method is allowed in React JS, which the latter overrides the former?

```
class Test extends React.Component { render() { return(<span>First label</span>); } render(){ return( <span>Second label</span>);} }
```

the above code renders "Second Label" and compiles fine. Is this intentional or a bug in React JS?

Comment: This is not React specific, but rather how JavaScript classes work. `class Foo { bar() { return 1; } bar() { return 2; }}; new Foo().bar();`

Comment: A class is an object. Can't have duplicate properties in any object and the last instance will override prior one when it is compiled. Is no different than `{foo:1,foo:2} //produces {foo:2}`

Answer (score 1):

A class is basically syntactic sugar on top of a function:

```js
class foo {}

console.log(typeof foo);
```

The methods in the class are existing as properties on the prototype of the function object (this function object actually is the class. More on prototypes [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)).

For example:

```js
class foo{
 bar () {console.log('random function')}
}

console.dir(foo.prototype.bar)
```

When you are declaring a second method with the same name, you are declaring a property with the same name on an object (i.e. the foo.prototype object). The newer declared property (i.e. method) will simply overwrite the existing property (i.e. older method).